# Doctrine - relation vs in-object collection saving

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity-relationship

I work with symfony2 & doctrine ;

I have 2 entities : `Question` and `Answer`. Logically, i would make a 1:* relation to link them.

But since the `Answer` objects are not related to anything else, will never be indexed (or accessed) outside of their `Question`. So I make the `Question` persistent, with an attribute $answers which contains an array of `Answer`s objects.

It worked fine until now. I want to take advantage of the Sonata Admin Forms, but it work only with a persistent layer (ORM or ODM).

So my questions will be :

1. Is it "bad practice" to save a collection of objects in an persistent object attribute ?
2. If I reverse my choice (make Answer Persistent), will it impact a lot my application ?

Comment: "Bad practice" is to store partial values within one cell in relational database, according to normalization theory.

Comment: @CORRUPT What do you mean by "partial values" ?

Comment: Not atomic values, that may be divided in two or more parts.

Comment: Alright, this answer my first question, thanks.

Comment: Yes. It will give you more options, if database changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it **is** a bad practice. And a very **bad** one.

I'm currently refactoring an inherited application that has a lot of serialized objects and arrays stored in columns and I want to smother the bastards — I mean the original developers.

Doing that creates a lot of problems. For example, you can't use the same database from another language. Or you can't even move or rename a class that was used for serialization, because deserialization will no longer work. It also makes both the application and database hard to grasp and mantain.

As a general rule, keep your database application independent. That is, never assume a particular language or framework that will use the database. Always design the database so that it can be accessed by apps written in different languages or even directly from command line doing plain SQL queries.

If nothing else convinces you, just keep in mind that an unstable person might eventually inherit your code. We've all heard the stories of people coming to office and shooting their colleagues ;)

Comment: My last reticence was about performances. But yeah, i wasn't looking at the right place (code portability).